# Requested resource is not available when changing action name

Tags: grails

I have an ajax call fire when an element is clicked. The ajax goes to a controller.

```
function(){

  $.ajax({
                    url: "/GAIA/RemoveCE/removeFlow",
                    type: "get",
                    data:  {id:id},
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload()
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log("ERROR");
                        console.log(xhr.readyState);
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                    }

                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

I have one action called "removeFlow" and one action called "removeMachine" on this controller.

```
def removeFlow(Long id){
    println id
}

def removeMachine(Long id){
    println id
}
```

When ajax is called to trigger "removeFlow" nothing is printed.

When ajax is called to trigger "removeMachine" id is printed correctly.

The error message received on both calls is 404 resoure is not available which I understand, since I haven't implemented a view and I am not redirecting. I do not understand why nothing is printed however.

This is running on grails 2.5.6

Edit:

This is the error I am getting on developer console (when element is clicked and ajax is fired):

jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false&encoding=UTF-8:9631 GET http://localhost:8080/GAIA/removeCE/removeFlow?id=41&_=1505308707652 404 (Not Found)

If I manually enter the URL (/GAIA/removeCE/removeFlow?id=41) i get this:

:8080/GAIA/removeCE/removeFlow?id=41:1 GET http://localhost:8080/GAIA/removeCE/removeFlow?id=41 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It is most likely the resource is not available on the server, or at a different URL, confirm the URL path with a browser first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy action you need to render something as a response to the ajax call, otherwise your call goes successfully but it will returns the 404 error.
Change your code as follows.

```
def removeFlow(Long id){
    println id
    // render anything string or ( List / Map as Json)
    render "Deleted Id:"+id+" successfully"
}


def removeMachine(Long id){
    println id
 // render anything string or ( List / Map as Json)
    render "Deleted Id:"+id+" successfully"
}
```

// Receive response in ajax success as

```
success: function( response) {
      console.log(response)
     //OR 
     alert(response);
 }
```

//Get Url in ajax using link taglib

```
url: '<g:createLink controller="removeCE" action="removeFlow"/>'
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, and when I enter your code and change the ajax call to call "removeMachine" it renders fine.

However if i call "removeFlow" it still gives me 404 resource not available error.

It seems really weird and I am probably overlooking something simple

Comment: @jacob88 nice..!

Comment: So unfortunately the problem still stands :-)

Comment: 404 (not found) gets only if your path to reach that resource is wrong (may be something spelling mistake / code not compiled properly ) or the above case. ideally you should have the render statement to notify ajax call, you can restart your app once.

Comment: You can simply hit call from browsers address bar and send params, verify the call

Comment: Is your actions are gsp's?

Comment: If i try ..../GAIA/removeCE/removeMachine?id=41 it renders fine and it prints to console.

If i try .../GAIA/removeCE/removeFlow?id=41 nothing happens, except in developer console on google chrome i get 404 error :\

Comment: See I updated answer to get url by using create link tag lib, try that to get valid path

Comment: Still the same :\ I am not sure that the path is the issue. Since the other action works i'm guessing the path to the controller must be valid.

Comment: @jacob88 If you have this  "RemoveCE" controller name then it should be used as "removeCE" in lowercase fiorst letter, I think this will hep you, updated my answer.

Comment: Still the same :\ But I appreciate your ideas :)

Comment: Do clean and restart app once, I don't think that, anything is wrong now.

Comment: I have, several times. I have updated the question with the error message from google chrome developer console.

Comment: Check your urlMappings groovy for controller name mapping

Comment: this is my URL mapping:

"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

Comment: Do grails clean before restart app if you renamed action / controller or create new controller from command line delete existing one

Comment: Tried clean-all and deleting the controller. Did not help :\

Comment: This is so strange,  i cant believe  it technically!

Comment: No me neither. I have now renamed the method to removeFlowTest and now it works.... How can that make a difference? :)

Comment: Something might not be synced, might be cached older name server side.  Nice finally you got resolution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I will mark your answer as correct since it helped me get to the renaming and the problem probably likes with something not in sync as you said.